# How do I save text with js

Tags: javascript

I don't understand where my mistake is. The text is saved in local storage but is not displayed on the page (paragraph).
How can I correct the mistake ?

```js
  function saveText() { 
  let demo = document.getElementById("demo").value;
  window.localStorage.textarea = demo; 
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = demo;  
 
}  
  window.onload = function () {
 if (localStorage.getItem ("textarea")) 
 document.getElementById ("test").InsideHTML = localStorage.getItem 
   ("textarea"); 
}
```

```html
    <input id="demo"></input>
    <button onclick="saveText()" type="button">save</button> 
 
 
    <p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: What's `var dem = demo;` supposed to do?

Comment: You never define `demo`?

Comment: I thought I had to do a demo in a variable so that I could send in the paragraph id, sorry I'm just learning, I don't know everything)

Comment: demo is text that you write in the input, is define

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define `demo` before using it:

```js
function saveText() { 
     let demo = document.getElementById("demo").value;
     window.localStorage.textarea = demo;
     var dem = demo; //this is not necessary
     document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = dem; //use demo instead
}
```

```html
<input id="demo"></input>
<button onclick="saveText()" type="button">save</button> 
<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: Why after the refresh on the page the text in the paragraph disappears?

Comment: This is because you are not assigning the stored value on load. To do this, add ``window.onload = function(){ if(localStorage.getItem("textarea")) document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("textarea"); }``

Comment: I changed the way you wrote and the text is not displayed, maybe I'm wrong somewhere.
(I updated the js code in the post, can you please see where I get the wrong code above)

Comment: The load function should be outside ``saveText``

Comment: I changed the code and it still doesn't work, did I do something wrong?
I updated the code above js.

Comment: Use ``innerHTML`` instead of ``InsideHTML``

Comment: now everything is working, thank you for your patience and help, all the best